# Where does this unknown list of variables come from?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Proposition: If $\psi$ is a subformula of $\phi$ and $\phi'$ results from replacing $0$ or more occurs of $\psi$ in $\phi$ per a well formed formula $\rho$ and each free variable of $\psi$ and $\rho$ that it's also a bound variable of $\phi$ occurs in the list $y_1,y_2,...,y_k,$ then $$\vdash [\forall y_1...\forall y_k(\psi\leftrightarrow\rho)]\to(\phi\leftrightarrow\phi')$$

My question is how will I know that some variable will occur\appear in that unknow list $y_1,y_2,...,y_k$? Doesn't this list have to have some property?

I don't understand this proposition.

Comment: Let’s walk into this from the other side: which lists $y_1,\ldots$ allow us to make that formula derivable for arbitrary $\phi,\psi,\rho$? Is there a minimal one?

Comment: @arseniiv no, I don't know what are you talking about. Minimal one? what's that?

Comment: Some list with less variables than in all the others. Also, suppose a list $y_1,\ldots,y_k$ and $\phi,\psi,\rho$ satisfy the proposition’s premise—would the list with some $y_{k+1}$ added and $\phi,\psi,\rho$ also satisfy the premise?

Comment: @arseniiv I think no,because the premise is only for $k$ variables.

Comment: But the proposition holds for any $k$.

Comment: @arseniiv So yes, it holds for $k+1$

Comment: Now consider a list of precisely those variables which are free in $\psi$ or $\rho$ and at the same time bounded in $\phi$. Should any other list, for which and $\phi,\psi,\rho$ the premise is applicable, contain this list?

Comment: So, erm, It all should have become a bit more transparent, than it was at the start. I don’t know what to add, or at least what to add right now. Sorry. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most propositions, the one you quoted is intended to be true for all values of the symbols in it. In the present case, this means: For all formulas $\phi,\phi',\psi,\rho$, all natural numbers $k$, and all lists $y_1,\dots,y_k$ of $k$ variables, if the hypothesis of your proposition holds then so does the conclusion.

So you're **given** that the $y$'s include all the variables that are free in $\psi$ or in $\rho$ and bound in $\phi$; that's part of the hypoothesis. You're not expected to figure out what those $y$'s are.

(By the way, "bounded" in the proposition is a typo; it should be "bound".)

Comment: Shouldn't be all the free variables that are in $\psi$ **and** in $\rho$ instead of **or**?

Comment: I made a lot of typos that's because english is not my tongue mother :/ but feel free to correct me.

Comment: The variables that are free in at lest one of $\psi$ and $\rho$.

Comment: Isn't the same as say all the free variables of $\psi$ and all the free variables of $\rho$? In the statement says each free variables of $\psi$ and $\rho$

Comment: All the free variables of $\psi$ and all the free variables of $\rho$ together are the variables that are free in $\psi$ or free in $\rho$.